# Configure Apache to accept any host requests

Tags: php, apache, symfony, web, dns

My website is running on Apache, and I am using Symfony version 3.0.9 framework. it is a click tracking application.

Now, my website's users will have to assign a costume. (point a CNAME record to my website).

```
click.User01Domain.example >> CNAME >> myWebsite.example
track.User02Domain.example >> CNAME >> myWebsite.example
trk.User03Domain.example   >> CNAME >> myWebsite.example
...
```

I m wondering how to make Apache/Symfony accept any host requests?

Comment: Apache won't care what the host is unless the `mywebsite.com` domain is served from a virtual host. By default, all traffic that's not routed to a named virtual host will go to the default host (the first one defined). Symfony shouldn't care what the host name is.

Comment: Define only one VirtualHost for the port you are listening on (port 80 for http).  In that one VH, do not put `ServerName`, nor `ServerAlias` directives.  This way Apache will use that configuration section for all connections on port 80.

Comment: This page: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html explains in detail how Apache choose which VirtualHost to serve based on the incoming query.